# aggregate and distribute time series data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation, pandas-resample

I have some time series data in a pandas data frame like this:

| begin | end | mw_values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-14 11:16:00 | 2021-09-14 11:27:11 | 0 |
| 2021-09-14 11:27:11 | 2021-09-14 11:30:00 | 100 |
| 2021-09-14 11:30:00 | 2021-09-14 11:33:59 | 1200 |
| 2021-09-14 11:33:59 | 2021-09-14 11:39:42 | 600 |
| 2021-09-14 11:39:42 | 2021-09-14 11:59:59 | 400 |

I need the sum of the mw_values distributed into 15 minutes time slots like this:

| time_slots_15_min | sum_mw_values |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-14 11:00 | 0 |
| 2021-09-14 11:15 | 100 |
| 2021-09-14 11:30 | 2200 |
| 2021-09-14 11:45 | 0 |
| 2021-09-14 12:00 | 0 |

Does someone have any idea how I can achieve this?

Note that the intervals between begin and end may overlap 2 time slots. Then the value must be involved in the sum of the time slot where it begins; e.g. the mw_value of 400 in the example from above.

Comment: Are the "end" values actually relevant?

Comment: @Riley it looks like only the beginning value matters. both answers reindex by the `"begin"` column and then resample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resample your dataframe so sum the data in 15 minute bins. Then you can reindex that frame so it matches your desired start/end/frequency times.

```py
freq = "15min"
new_index = pd.date_range(
    "2021-09-14 11:00:00", "2021-09-14 12:00:00", freq=freq
)

out = (
    df.resample(freq, on="begin")["mw_values"]
    .sum()
    .reindex(new_index, fill_value=0)
    .to_frame("sum_mw_values")
)

print(out)
                     sum_mw_values
2021-09-14 11:00:00              0
2021-09-14 11:15:00            100
2021-09-14 11:30:00           2200
2021-09-14 11:45:00              0
2021-09-14 12:00:00              0
```

Comment: Hi Cameron, thank you very much. Your solution has solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can reindex your DataFrame by the `begin` column, insert two new rows to ensure that the beginning time starts at `11:00` and that the end time is `12:00`), then and then use `.resample("15min").sum()` which will work for a `DatetimeIndex` (the documentation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) if you want to read further):

```
## in case your column isn't already a datetime
df["begin"] = pd.to_datetime(df["begin"])

df = df.set_index("begin")

## add beginning and ending times to df
df_start_end = pd.DataFrame({"end": ["2021-09-14 11:15:00","2021-09-14 12:15:00"], "mw_values":[0]}, index=[pd.to_datetime("2021-09-14 11:00:00"),pd.to_datetime("2021-09-14 12:00:00")])
df_final = pd.concat([df_start_end,df]).sort_index()
```

This is what `df_final` looks like:

```
                                     end  mw_values
2021-09-14 11:00:00  2021-09-14 11:15:00          0
2021-09-14 11:16:00  2021-09-14 11:27:11          0
2021-09-14 11:27:11  2021-09-14 11:30:00        100
2021-09-14 11:30:00  2021-09-14 11:33:59       1200
2021-09-14 11:33:59  2021-09-14 11:39:42        600
2021-09-14 11:39:42  2021-09-14 11:59:59        400
2021-09-14 12:00:00  2021-09-14 12:15:00          0
```

Then we resample and sum every 15 minutes over the `DatetimeIndex`:

```
## sum by every 15 minutes from the start to end time
df_final.resample("15min").sum().reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"time_slots_15_min","mw_values":"sum_mw_values"})
```

Output:

```
    time_slots_15_min  sum_mw_values
0 2021-09-14 11:00:00              0
1 2021-09-14 11:15:00            100
2 2021-09-14 11:30:00           2200
3 2021-09-14 11:45:00              0
4 2021-09-14 12:00:00              0
```

Comment: Hi Derek, thank you for your help. I have used Cameron's solution because it's shorter. However, your similar, but more verbose approach with the comments helped me to understand how resampling works in pandas.

Comment: @ThomasKutsch No worries, I am glad to have helped!